# How to select N characters from an AS400/DB2 Database Column

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I have an AS400/DB2 Database, with a column of type character. This column represents a date, example:

```
COLUMNDATA
20091101
20091201
20100101
... etc.
```

I want to select on one hand the "year" (first 4 characters), and on the other, the "month" (the following two characters).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store dates as, well, dates and not strings.  But, you can do what you want as:

```
select substr(columndata, 1, 4) as Year, substr(columndata, 5, 2) as Month
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks!! And regarding your comment, yes I know, but it isn't my database. I just work with it!